# Why do .NET threads have inferior performance to separate .NET processes?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

Lately I've been observing an interesting phenomenon, and before I reengineer my whole software architecture based on it, I'd like to know why this happens, and if it's perhaps possible to make thread performance on par with process performance.

Generally, the task is to download certain data. If we make one process with 6 threads, based on the Parallel library, the downloads take around 10s.

If we, however, make 6 processes, each being single threaded, and download the same data, the whole thing will only take around 6s.

The numbers are thoroughly verified and statistically significant, so do take them for granted.

The observation holds over a large (100s of trials) dataset and I've observed no deviation from this behavior.

Basically, the question is, why a non-synchronizing multithreaded process is slower than a few separate processes with the exact same working code, and how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Note: I've read similar questions but the answers haven't been satisfactory and practical.

Comment: You didn't include nearly enough information to properly answer your question, but my crystal ball is telling me this could be because .Net limits the number of concurrent HTTP connections to a single server to 2 by default. See [ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit).

Comment: Call ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(6, 10000) and try again.

Comment: TPL's default task scheduler can take a while to spin up new threads. It's designed for short, CPU bound tasks not IO bound. So by creating processes you're probably getting those in on the action faster. Also the .NET garbage collector can sometimes block all threads (depending on which version you're using). Obviously one process = one GC so there's less blocking. TL;DR wild guesses: provide more information.

Comment: You seem to be labouring under the misapprehension that paralellised = faster. Parallelisation may be faster, it could be a heck of a lot slower as well, depends on the task.

Comment: Also, seeing your code would help. It often matters *how* you are doing it.

Comment: any chance you can add some code? I stumbled on to this answer because I was looking to compare thread and process.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the same as svick's: you probably have some kind of bottleneck inserted by the runtime.

In general, you can use a tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to see how the 10 downloads are interleaving.  In your case, I would expect that there would only be two active at any one time and that once one finishes, another will start immediately.

Before you go and change the setting, you should understand why it's there.  It is written into the HTTP spec as suggested client behavior so as to not overwhelm the server.  If your code is going to be distributed out to hundreds/thousands/millions of machines, you should consider the effects of 10 simultaneous downloads per client.